# How to send a Wake-on-LAN magic packet using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, wake-on-lan

I want to send a WOL magic packet using PowerShell, without falling back on any third party tools.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the working PowerShell **one-liner** I am using to send a WakeOnLan packet:

`$mac = '01-23-45-67-89-AB'; [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces() | Where-Object { $_.NetworkInterfaceType -ne [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType]::Loopback -and $_.OperationalStatus -eq [System.Net.NetworkInformation.OperationalStatus]::Up } | ForEach-Object { $targetPhysicalAddressBytes = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.PhysicalAddress]::Parse(($mac.ToUpper() -replace '[^0-9A-F]','')).GetAddressBytes(); $packet = [byte[]](,0xFF * 102); 6..101 | Foreach-Object { $packet[$_] = $targetPhysicalAddressBytes[($_ % 6)] }; $client = [System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient]::new([System.Net.IPEndPoint]::new(($_.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses | Where-Object { $_.Address.AddressFamily -eq [System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily]::InterNetwork })[0].Address, 0)); try { $client.Send($packet, $packet.Length,[System.Net.IPEndPoint]::new([System.Net.IPAddress]::Broadcast, 9)) | Out-Null } finally { $client.Dispose() } }`

And here is a more **readable** version:

```
$mac = '01-23-45-67-89-AB';
[System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces() | Where-Object { $_.NetworkInterfaceType -ne [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType]::Loopback -and $_.OperationalStatus -eq [System.Net.NetworkInformation.OperationalStatus]::Up } | ForEach-Object {
    $networkInterface = $_
    $localIpAddress = ($networkInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses | Where-Object { $_.Address.AddressFamily -eq [System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily]::InterNetwork })[0].Address
    $targetPhysicalAddress = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.PhysicalAddress]::Parse(($mac.ToUpper() -replace '[^0-9A-F]',''))
    $targetPhysicalAddressBytes = $targetPhysicalAddress.GetAddressBytes()
    $packet = [byte[]](,0xFF * 102)
    6..101 | Foreach-Object { $packet[$_] = $targetPhysicalAddressBytes[($_ % 6)] }
    $localEndpoint = [System.Net.IPEndPoint]::new($localIpAddress, 0)
    $targetEndpoint = [System.Net.IPEndPoint]::new([System.Net.IPAddress]::Broadcast, 9)
    $client = [System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient]::new($localEndpoint)
    try { $client.Send($packet, $packet.Length, $targetEndpoint) | Out-Null } finally { $client.Dispose() }
}
```

All common **MAC address formats** are supported and casing doesn't matter, for example:

- `0123456789aB`
- `01-23-45-67-89-aB`
- `01:23:45:67:89:aB`
- `0123.4567.89aB`

Works in `powershell.exe` (.NET Framework) and `pwsh.exe` (.NET/.Net Core).

Loosely based on code from [Wake on LAN using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861873/wake-on-lan-using-c-sharp).

Comment: You probably want to give the MAC without ':' signs.

Comment: @BartoszRosa There are multiple formats supported (including macs without `:` separators). See [PhysicalAddress.Parse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress.parse) for more information.

Comment: Yes, but in my case, PowerShell `Parse()` method raises an exception with this format. In any case, thanks for the code.

Comment: @BartoszRosa Yes, if you are using an older PowerShell version (like one that ships with Windows instead of `pwsh`), it will not support this format (see [PhysicalAddress.Parse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress.parse)). I'll can change the MAC format in the sample code to something that works in all versions.

Comment: Note you'd have to be on the same network, fast startup would have to be disabled in windows 10, probably on dells wake on lan would have to be enabled, and deep sleep disabled.

Comment: I updated the answer so that all common Mac address formats work with both: `powershell.exe` and `pwsh.exe`.

Comment: The dell bios utility "cctk" doesn't work with all dell models either.