# Getting a network interface's multicast addresses in .NET on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core

I am trying to build an application in .NET 6 that can send wake-on-LAN magic packets.

I'm following this answer on Stack Overflow to implement this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58043033/1992818

This works great on Windows, but doesn't work on Ubuntu, because the IPInterfaceProperties.MulticastAddresses property is empty.

The basic code is the following:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface networkInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            IPInterfaceProperties iPInterfaceProperties = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();

            // count will always be 0
            int count = iPInterfaceProperties.MulticastAddresses.Count;

        }
```

Is there a different way to get this working on Ubuntu from .NET?

Comment: Did you try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65529803/12354911). It uses `BroadCastAddress`

Comment: @Eldar That seems to work! A much simpler way of doing things. Would you like to submit that as an answer?

Comment: That would be a duplicate I think, but glad to help.